# I wrote this Hamming Encoding code for class. Why is it so slow?

Tags: c++, file, operating-system, hamming-code

I wrote this for my OS class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//encodes a file using the (8,4) Hamming Code.
//usage : HammingEncode.out < inputFile > outputFile 
int main() {
    unsigned char const codebook[] = {0x00, 0x1E, 0x2D, 0x33, 0x4B, 0x55, 0x66, 0x78, 0x87, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xB4, 0xCC, 0xD2, 0xE1, 0xFF};
    unsigned char in, nextByte;
    unsigned char const leftMask = 0xF0, rightMask = 0x0F;

    in = std::cin.get();
    while (!std::cin.eof()) {
        nextByte = (in & leftMask) >> 4;
        std::cout << codebook[nextByte];
        nextByte = in & rightMask;
        std::cout << codebook[nextByte];
        in = std::cin.get();
    }
}
```

I then decided to test its speed (just to see) on the Old Testamenet form the King James Bible.  This was our standard test file for a Data Structures Class which was taught in Java, and we could sort it and Huffman Encode it in basically no time, yet this takes quite a long time to encode.  What is going on?

Comment: Most likely, java was buffering your input and output for you. You are reading/writing one byte at a time here.

Comment: @Blorgbeard iostream does buffering just as well.

Comment: @j_kubik I stand corrected.

Comment: Wha are your compilation flags? Unoptimized code will be terribly slow in such cases, but optimization has the potential to speed it up by orders of magnitude.

Comment: @j_kubik g++ HammingEncode.cpp -O2 -o HammingEncode.out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::cin` is open in text-mode, and as such it is constantly on the lookout for all kinds of things to watch for (like newlines, etc).

Given the constant character sniffing by the `std::cin` input stream, i'm not surprised it takes longer, but it does seem a little excessive. the following, bypassing `iostream` and using `FILE` stream directly will probably do what you were expecting:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static unsigned char const codebook[] =
    {
        0x00, 0x1E, 0x2D, 0x33, 0x4B, 0x55, 0x66, 0x78,
        0x87, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xB4, 0xCC, 0xD2, 0xE1, 0xFF
    };

    for (int c = std::fgetc(stdin); c!=EOF; c=std::fgetc(stdin))
    {
        std::fputc(codebook[c >> 4], stdout);
        std::fputc(codebook[c & 0x0F], stdout);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I tested the *exact* code above on an 10MB random file loaded with chars ranging from `a` to `z`, and the results were ridiculously long when using `std::cin` and `std::cout`. Using the `FILE` streams directly, the difference was *enormous*. All of the code in this answer was tested with `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)` using `-O3` optimization.

**Using `FILE` streams**

```
time ./hamming < bigfile.txt > bigfile.ham 
real 0m1.855s
user 0m1.812s
sys  0m0.041s
```

**Using `std::cin` and `std::cout`**

```
time ./hamming < bigfile.txt > bigfile.ham
real 0m23.819s
user 0m7.416s
sys  0m16.377s
```

**Using `std::cin` and `std::cout` with `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);`**

```
time ./hamming < bigfile.txt > bigfile.ham
real 0m24.867s
user 0m7.705s
sys  0m17.118s
```

In summary, *ouch*. Of note is the time spent in *system*. If I get a chance to update this with the `std::istream::get()` and `put()` methods I will, but honestly I don't expect any miracles on that. Unless there is some magic (to me, not to others) way of turning *off* io xlat from `std::cin` the `FILE` streams may be a reasonable alternative. I haven't yet investigated whether slurping `std::cin`'s `rdbuf()` is a viable option either, but it may too have promise.

---

**Edit: Using `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`**

Using the streambuf iterator class has a significant improvement, as it essentially bypasses all the inline slat junk, but it still isn't as efficient as `FILE` streams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static unsigned char const codebook[] =
    {
        0x00, 0x1E, 0x2D, 0x33, 0x4B, 0x55, 0x66, 0x78,
        0x87, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xB4, 0xCC, 0xD2, 0xE1, 0xFF
    };

    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> cin_it(std::cin), cin_eof;
    std::for_each(cin_it, cin_eof, [](char c)
        {
          std::cout.put(static_cast<char>(codebook[static_cast<unsigned char>(c) >> 4]));
          std::cout.put(static_cast<char>(codebook[static_cast<unsigned char>(c) & 0x0F]));
        });

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Results:

```
time ./hamming < bigfile.txt > bigfile.ham

real 0m6.062s
user 0m5.795s
sys  0m0.053s
```

Note that `system` is now comparable to the `FILE` stream results, but the overhead from rest of the iostream templates in `user` seems a sore point (but still better than the other `iostream` attempts). You win some, you lose some =P

---

**Edit: Unbuffered System IO**

In effort to be completely fair, bypassing all runtime buffering and relying solely on the system calls to do this madness, the following is also worth noting:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static unsigned char const codebook[] =
    {
        0x00, 0x1E, 0x2D, 0x33, 0x4B, 0x55, 0x66, 0x78,
        0x87, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xB4, 0xCC, 0xD2, 0xE1, 0xFF
    };

    unsigned char c;
    while (read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1)> 0)
    {
        unsigned char duo[2] =
        {
            codebook[ c >> 4 ],
            codebook[ c & 0x0F ]
        };
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, duo, sizeof(duo));
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The results, as you would expect, were dreadful:

```
time ./hamming < bigfile.txt > bigfile.ham

real 0m26.509s
user 0m2.370s
sys  0m24.087s
```

Comment: `static_cast<unsigned char>(c)` is superfluous; the `fgetc` function is defined to return the value of a character converted to the range of `unsigned char`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb the inner one (indexing codebook) ? yeah, its a holdover from the `char` code of `std::cin.get(c)` when `c` was `char` and not `int`. Probably should have stripped that out. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Could you also test home-made buffering, like I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Awesome reply, thanks a lot!  I figured there was a lot of hardware overhead from the read/write head, but as someone still learning c++ this was great :D

Answer (score 2):

I got close to an order of magnitude improvement by making 2 small changes.

1. Adding `std::ios_base::synch_with_stdio(false)` (no noticeable difference, though the impact is often implementation specific)
2. Buffering the output before writing (this made the most difference)

The updated code looks like this:

```
int main()
{

    //encodes a file using the (8,4) Hamming Code.
    //usage : HammingEncode.out < inputFile > outputFile 
        unsigned char const codebook[] = { 0x00, 0x1E, 0x2D, 0x33, 0x4B, 0x55, 0x66, 0x78, 0x87, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xB4, 0xCC, 0xD2, 0xE1, 0xFF };
        unsigned char in, nextByte;
        unsigned char const leftMask = 0xF0, rightMask = 0x0F;
        std::stringstream os;

        std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
        in = std::cin.get();
        while (std::cin) {
            nextByte = (in & leftMask) >> 4;
            os.put(codebook[nextByte]);
            nextByte = in & rightMask;
            os.put(codebook[nextByte]);
            in = std::cin.get();
        }
        std::cout << os.rdbuf();
}
```

**Update**

I tried one more implementation - using the underlying `std::streambuf`.

On my system the original code was taking around **14 seconds** to process the full King James Bible - around 4.3 MB

The code in my original attempt took around **2.1 seconds** to process.

This new implementation took **0.71 seconds** to process the same document.

```
int main()
{

    //encodes a file using the (8,4) Hamming Code.
    //usage : HammingEncode.out < inputFile > outputFile 
    unsigned char const codebook[] = { 0x00, 0x1E, 0x2D, 0x33, 0x4B, 0x55, 0x66, 0x78, 0x87, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xB4, 0xCC, 0xD2, 0xE1, 0xFF };
    unsigned char in, nextByte;
    unsigned char const leftMask = 0xF0, rightMask = 0x0F;
    std::stringstream os;

    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

std::streambuf * pbuf = std::cin.rdbuf();
    do {
        in = pbuf->sgetc();
        nextByte = (in & leftMask) >> 4;
        os << codebook[nextByte];
        nextByte = in & rightMask;
        os << codebook[nextByte];
    } while (pbuf->snextc() != EOF);
    std::cout << os.rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: +1 the streambuf read-side makes sense, since it is essentially what using an `istreambuf_iterator<>` will do, less the overhead. Considering your file test size vs the 10MB I tested is approx 2.3x smaller, the difference vs. a 10MB file is near-spot-on with expectations. nice write up.

Answer (score 1):

C++ iostreams has bad opinion for being rather inefficient, although different numbers suggest that it's rather quality-of-implementation issue, rather than iostream disadvantage.

Anyway, just to be sure that it's not anything like slow hdd you might compare execution time to e.g.

```
cat file1 > file2
```

Of cource `cat` will be a bit quicker, as it doesn't double the size of your data.

Then try to compare efficieny of your code with following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char buffer[1024*1024]; // 1MB buffer should be enough

    while (!eof(STDIN_FILENO)){
        size_t len = read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer[0], 1024*1024);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buffer[0], len);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buffer[0], len);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry, my bad. Try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char buffer[1024*1024]; // 1MB buffer should be enough

    size_t len = read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer[0], 1024*1024);

    while(len > 0){
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buffer[0], len);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buffer[0], len);
        len = read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer[0], 1024*1024);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not compile, it doesn't recognize eof.  I replaced it with feof and it compiled, but gave me a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, for each byte you read, you then write 2 bytes. So output file will be double size of the input. If your input is big enough - total IO (read + 2 * write) time will be significant.

In Huffman coding this is not the case - since you usually write less than you read, and total IO time will be much lower.

**EDIT:**
As *Blorgbeard* said, it can be the difference in buffering. C++ also does buffering, but may be default buffers are much smaller than in Java. Also the fact that the HDD head should constantly jump between reading file in one location and then writing in another - significantly impacts overall IO performance.

In any case, encoding should be done in chunks in order to ensure sequential read and write of large blocks

Comment: Well, yes.  But I don't understand why it takes so much longer to write a file twice as long than it did to write it directly in Java.  Like if I wrote this file twice in Java it would be much faster.  So I want to know why this code takes 30 seconds to write 8 MB

Comment: 30 seconds for 8MB sounds indeed very slow. I would try experiment: try just to read the file byte after byte, and for each byte just write the read byte twice into output file. This will allow to understand whether the problem is in IO or in the algorithm itself (not likely). But it's important to read byte and then immediately write twice (and not read into buffer and then to write the buffer twice)

Comment: @DenisItskovitch I'm not sure I know how to write directly without using iostream, which buffers.  I can't do

    nextByte = std::cin.get() & rightMask;
    std::cout << nextByte;  std::cout nextByte;  ?

Comment: @JonCohen I didn't mean directly. I meant just read/write exactly as you did in your question, but without encoding

Comment: Tried that, takes just as long :(

Comment: @JonCohen now try to do the same experiment, but first read into buffer of let's say 64K and then write this array twice. This should improve the performance